# get data from a JSON string according to the value of another cell

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm looking for an idea to help me extract the data from one cell("data"). When the value from another cell ("id") is for example 11, I want to display the corresponding parsed value from "data" into rows and columns from another Excel-Worksheet.I'm using the library (VBA-JSON v2.3.1 JsonConverter)

I have the following JSON-Object:

```
 {

"Messages":[
    {
        "internalDeviceId":11,
        "rawJson":"{\"temperature\":22.6,\"humidity\":37,\"light\":1,\"motion\":1,\"co2\":640,\"vdd\":3.647}"
    },
    {
        "internalDeviceId":12,
        "rawJson":"{\"humidity\":30,\"pressure\":1000,\"CO2\":700,\"vdd\":3.654}"
    },
    {
        "internalDeviceId":13,
        "rawJson":"{\"latitude\":47.654,\"longitude\":9.654,\"vdd\":3.432}"
    },
    {
        "internalDeviceId":11,
        "rawJson":"{\"temperature\":23.0,\"humidity\":38,\"light\":20,\"motion\":0,\"co2\":665,\"vdd\":3.621}"
    },
{
        "internalDeviceId":11,
        "rawJson":"{\"temperature\":22.1,\"humidity\":35,\"light\":15,\"motion\":1,\"co2\":650,\"vdd\":3.425}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I got the data from a rest API with a VBA code and that is working. At the moment I get the following information in excel:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
        Dim response2 As String
        Dim json1 As Object
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        strUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/devices/11/"
        Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        With hReq
            Set ws2 = Worksheets(3)
            .Open "GET", strUrl, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & apitoken
            .Send
            response2 = hReq.responseText
            Set json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response2)
            k = 2
                For Each item In json1("Messages")
                ws2.Cells(k, 3) = item("externalDeviceId")
                ws2.Cells(k, 8) = item("rawJson")
                k = k + 1
                Next item
         End With
```

I just want to split the information from "data" in rows and columns based on a certain  "id" for example in this case 11. The structure from "data" depends on "id".  I want to do this in VBA without PowerQuery. I was searching for hours and didn't find a solution.

I know that the item I am returning is, itself, a JSON string. To split the information from it, I create another JSON object. I don't know how I can get the information from data into rows and columns because of the different structures of "data".

How can I access these different values depending on the "id"?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you will want to handle all id cases being written to same range then you could use a helper dict, initialised with all the possible column headers (keys of `rawJson` dictionary) and with empty values. As you process each intended row to write out, `item("rawJson")`, simply overwrite the existing `vbNullString` values where present in both dictionaries. Keys not present in current row will be left with `vbNullString` values, due to `On Error Resume Next` wrapper inside helper function.

If you only care about id = 11 then add in an `If ... End If`

```
For Each item In json1
    id = item("internalDeviceId")
    If id = 11 Then
        Set dict = GetHomogenousRow(id, headers, item("rawJson"))
        r = r + 1
        .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.Values)
    End If
Next
```

If you are intending to pick up id from the sheet that is also easy enough to incorporate, though I don't know what would stop each call with id of 11 from being identical; unless website updates very rapidly and there were a timestamp field - seems unlikely for basic weather info.

---

N.B. Not tested. Please provide valid json sample.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutObservations()
    Dim response2 As String, url As String, hReq As Object, apitoken As String
    
    url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/devices/11/"
    apitoken = "xyz"
    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & apitoken
        .Send
        response2 = hReq.responseText
    End With
    
    Dim headers(), id As Long, json1 As Object
    Dim item As Object, r As Long, ws2 As Worksheet
    
    headers = Array("id", "temperature", "humidity", "light", "motion", "co2", "vdd")
    
    Set json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response2)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    r = 1
    
    With ws2
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For Each item In json1
            id = item("internalDeviceId")
            Set dict = GetHomogenousRow(id, headers, item("rawJson"))
            r = r + 1
            .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.Values)
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetHomogenousRow(ByVal id As Long, ByRef headers As Variant, ByVal inputDict As Scripting.Dictionary) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long, key As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        dict.Add headers(i), vbNullString
    Next
    
    dict("id") = id
    On Error Resume Next                         'ignore where key not present
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        dict(key) = inputDict(key)
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set GetHomogenousRow = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I could not test the code yet, because I do not feel well. As soon as I try it, I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi @QHarr! I was trying the code and it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. the following JSON-Object is right:

Comment: I have problems applying the code. I have attached a screenshot, where you can see where I have the error. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Hiya! You haven't said what the error is. Also, you have altered the code slightly partic on the For Each item line.